# Rails parse datetime in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting datetime string from the form and the example value is below:

```
2014-02-21 13:00:00
```

I want to be able to convert this into datetime before it gets saved in the model.

Is there a way to do this as Rails 4 seems to put wrong date in there automatically when it gets saved

Comment: What do you mean by: Rails seems to put the wrong date automatically?

Comment: It's on Heroku and my local time is Melbourne time

Answer (score 1):

Adding your timezone as default in `application.rb` like below should do the trick:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Time.zone.parse("2014-02-21 13:00:00")
```

instead of

```
Time.parse("2014-02-21 13:00:00")
```

as the latter will "assume the string is given in the system's time zone"

[Source and more about the topic](http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: How would you put this in model so that any datetime strings automatically converted inside model for example?

Comment: I would use [Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html). Something like `before_save` or `before_validation`, depending on your needs.

Comment: So if the field name was start then would you do something like `date = DateTime.zone.parse(:start)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to_time or to_date_time method.
It convert string into date time format

```
"2014-02-21 13:00:00".to_time 
"2014-02-21 13:00:00".to_datetime
```